# Where can I find the original (non-slipstreamed) Windows 10 1607 retail en-US ISO (MSDN)?

Tags: msdn

MSDN offers isos of all of the Windows OS software. The problem is that for Windows 10 1607, they only offer the "updated" version of the ISO, which has all updates through Jan. 2017 slipstreamed into it. This actually [causes issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/814362/removing-windows-10-built-in-apps-from-a-windows-10-image/866361#866361), so I'd really like the original ISO.

Am I just missing it on the MSDN page somewhere? Can anyone offer advice on how to get Microsoft to make it available once again?

Comment: Microsoft only offers the current ISO of a given feature release.  If you want an older version use a non-official Microsoft source.

Comment: "Can anyone offer advice on how to get Microsoft to make it available once again?" - We as end users cannot force Microsoft to do anything

Comment: @Ramhound - this is not true. They currently offer original 1703 and updated 1703. And they have a link to original 1511 (that doesn't work). Further, it is only the en-us version that has the updates slipstreamed - e.g., the Bulgarian version does not have the updates slipstreamed.

Comment: @Ramhound - I did not mean this super literally. Of course Microsoft is the only one that can publish something on MSDN. Rather, is there a good place to direct feedback or get Microsoft's attention in the hopes that they see/understand the feedback and possibly act on it?

Comment: Feedback Application; Otherwise out of scope here at Superuser on how and where to provide feedback to Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to get the original 1607 ISO from a Microsoft server.

First, you have to convince Microsoft that you are not running Windows. So use your favorite method to change your user-agent string to something else, or use not Windows. I used:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12
```

to be Safari on OSX. Then visit

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

(On windows this will direct you to the Media Creation Tool, which builds you a custom ISO not suitable for use with deployment tools like Microsoft Deployment Toolkit; but for non-windows users, you can get a real link to the original ISO.)

Pick the edition (I wanted Windows 10 Anniversary Update > Windows 10) and the language (English), and you'll be given custom links to the ISO after your request is "validated".

This doesn't help if you want the original 1511 en-US ISO (also not available on MSDN), and is obviously not as ideal as being able to go to MSDN to get original vesions of every Windows release.